# Android constant value to constant name (app:showAsAction="2")

Tags: android, xml

I've got some code I decompiled and I'm trying to figure out the constant names that go along with the constant values. In one of my xml files I see `app:showAsAction="2"`. Looks like, [according android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html), this can take values `"ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"` But how can I figure out which one? Sometimes I can find reference to the constant value-name mappings online but sometimes I cannot. Is there a way to find out for sure?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:icon="@drawable/my_drawable" android:enabled="false" android:title="my title" app:showAsAction="2"></item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can,

You need to look at the source of `android.view.MenuItem`. There are many constants defined there, including the one you need.

```
public static final int SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS = 2;
```

This is the source of `android.view.MenuItem` interface,

```
public interface MenuItem {
    /*
     * These should be kept in sync with attrs.xml enum constants for showAsAction
     */
    /** Never show this item as a button in an Action Bar. */
    public static final int SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER = 0;
    /** Show this item as a button in an Action Bar if the system decides there is room for it. */
    public static final int SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM = 1;
    /**
     * Always show this item as a button in an Action Bar.
     * Use sparingly! If too many items are set to always show in the Action Bar it can
     * crowd the Action Bar and degrade the user experience on devices with smaller screens.
     * A good rule of thumb is to have no more than 2 items set to always show at a time.
     */
    public static final int SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS = 2;

    /**
     * When this item is in the action bar, always show it with a text label even if
     * it also has an icon specified.
     */
    public static final int SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT = 4;

    /**
     * This item's action view collapses to a normal menu item.
     * When expanded, the action view temporarily takes over
     * a larger segment of its container.
     */
    public static final int SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW = 8;


    ...
}
```

[This](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/MenuItem.java) is link to the source code of `MenuItem` class